# PHP GearmanClient not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: php, gearman

I have this simple code:

```
<?php
$client = new \GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
```

This gives following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GearmanException: Failed to set exception option in /var/www/demo-admin/public-html/admin-generico/vendor/generico/components/tests/utils/test-gearman.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/demo-admin/public-html/admin-generico/vendor/generico/components/tests/utils/test-gearman.php(4): GearmanClient->addServer()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/demo-admin/public-html/admin-generico/vendor/generico/components/tests/utils/test-gearman.php on line 4
```

Gearman server is definitely running as confirmed by ps:

```
ps -A | grep gearman
25698 ?        00:00:00 gearmand
```

I installed php-gearman from ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman

Gearman version is 1.1.17

Comment: Can you list the steps you used to install the gearman server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @Kris Peeling gave an idea. I uninstalled everything gearman and installed again. Voila! Problem gone. I didn't have to use the localhost IP.
I referred this: https://www.patreon.com/posts/gearman-now-in-14627464

Answer (score 0):

The `addServer()` method requires a host parameter, even if the gearman server is running locally:

```
$client->addServer('127.0.0.1');
```

Even though the documentation says the default is the local server, I've found that it sometimes has to be specified to make that error go away.